# Hibernate 4 is not working c3p0 on JBoss 7

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, wildfly, spring-transactions, hibernate-4.x

When I deploy my Spring4-Hibernate-4 application on Jboss7, it throws error and deployment fails. Details:

Configuration code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.arg.utility.hibernate" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfigWS {

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryWS() throws SQLException, NamingException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSourceWS());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.arg.utility.hibernate.model" });
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return sessionFactory;
 }


@Bean
@Lazy
public DataSource dataSourceWS() throws SQLException, NamingException {
    InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = null;
    try{
         ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup(System.getProperty(UtilityConstants.JNDI_WS_DATASOURCE));
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Datasource lookup failed :"+e.getStackTrace());
    }
    return ds;
}


@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManagerWS(SessionFactory sessionFactoryWS) {
   HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
   txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryWS);
   return txManager;
}

  //----------------------HIBERNATE COMMON PROPERTIES CONFIG---------------------//
/**
 * 
 * @return properties object
 */
private Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    /*properties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider");  // commented
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5");  // commented
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20");  // commented
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "1800");  // commented
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50");*/  // commented
    return properties;        
}

}
```

Datasource entry in JBoss 7 standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/WSDataSource" pool-name="WSDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://dshost:3306/ds_name</connection-url>
                <connection-property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">
                    convertToNull
                </connection-property>
                <driver>com.mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>abc</user-name>
                    <password>abc@123</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>30000</background-validation-millis>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
    </datasource>
```

While deploying the application, I get the following error:

```
    <<< ServerService Thread Pool -- 68:2017/04/07 16:20:54.676:org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader::::: Context initialization failed  >>>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerWS' defined in com.arg.hibernate.config.HibernateConfigWS: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:55)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 22 more
```

When I uncomment the c3p0 properties setting lines in the config file, the application is successfully deployed (but later throws exception while creating connection). However, my requirement is that I don't have to use c3p0. So my queries:

1. Is it possible to run Hibernate 4 on Jboss 7 without using c3p0?
2. If yes, how? Is any other configuration needed?

Comment: Can you provide the value of `System.getProperty(UtilityConstants.JNDI_WS_DATASOURCE)`

Comment: @AlexBarnes it's a constant in properties file whose value is "java:/WSDataSource". The jndi look up is successful, no issue in that.

Comment: Good to know. And you're using the Hibernate 4 version of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` i.e. `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: Yes, both `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the stack trace it refers to `UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl`. This is where the exception is being thrown. Based on your configuration and the code in `ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService` I would have expected that this would be an instance of `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl` instead.

`AvailableSettings.DATASOURCE` is set by the `LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder` constructor if the `DataSource` has been provided which yours has. Are you sure that your JNDI lookup isn't silently returning `null`?

Comment: Thank you Alex. It was indeed returning null. It was a silly spelling mistake in properties file where the jndi name was declared. "Are you sure that your JNDI lookup isn't silently returning null?" This made the whole difference. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexBarnes, Can you please help me with this: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45546603/jndi-datasource-for-spring-4-hibernate-4-project-not-working-in-aws)